# Qt setPermissions not setting permisions

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm not sure why but my code bellow does not set permissions for a file.
Not sure what could be wrong with the code.

SYSTEM:
Windows XP Pro SP2.
Running in Admin account as admin.
Newest Qt framework and files.

```
//Get file permissions of ref file.
QFile::Permissions qpPerm1;
qpPerm1 = QFile::permissions("E:/dir1/dir2/File1.txt");

//Set file permissions of a file.
bool isOK=0;
isOK = QFile::setPermissions("E:/dir4/dir5/file2.txt",qpPerm1);
qout << "Perms set? " << isOK << endl;
```

Return value is TRUE... claims it set the permissions but it did not. 
To be clear, file2.txt is a copy of file1.txt.
I set permisions of file1 to be something but file2.txt has different permissions after I run my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was [written](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/26956) QT doesn't support changing access rights for groups on windows. For full control over file permissions try using Access Control List which is located in security descriptor.

[MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this:

> To retrieve the security descriptor of a file or directory object,
>   call the GetNamedSecurityInfo or GetSecurityInfo function. To change
>   the security descriptor of a file or directory object, call the
>   SetNamedSecurityInfo or SetSecurityInfo function.

I think in your case you could try GetNamedSecurityInfo from the first file and pass it to SetNamedSecurityInfo for the second one.

---

Also you can assign NULL ACL and it will reset all group permissions and grant full access for everyone:

```
SetNamedSecurityInfoA("C:\file.txt", SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentionning WinXP Pro SP2, I'll assume your files are on NTFS.

According to [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfile.html#Permission-enum) :

> Note that Qt does not by default check for permissions on NTFS file
>   systems, as this may decrease the performance of file handling
>   considerably. It is possible to force permission checking on NTFS by
>   including the following code in your source:
>
> ```
> extern Q_CORE_EXPORT int qt_ntfs_permission_lookup;
> ```
>
> Permission checking is then turned on and off by incrementing and
>   decrementing qt_ntfs_permission_lookup by 1.
>
> ```
> qt_ntfs_permission_lookup++; // turn checking on
> qt_ntfs_permission_lookup--; // turn it off again
> ```

Comment: Correct NTFS. Unfortunately, what you suggested did not work. The returned bools is 1 but still no change in perms. In fact there is no difference except code runs slower.