# how to set Windows file permissions in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, winapi, file-permissions, qt4.7

In my Qt 4.7.4 x64 C++ app I'm building in Qt Creator 2.5.0, I want to give full access to everyone for a file.  I'm using `QFile::setPermissions`, which I believe works fine for Mac and Linux, but it doesn't work for Windows.  According to [Qt setPermissions not setting permisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021645/qt-setpermissions-not-setting-permisions), I should use

```
SetNamedSecurityInfoA("C:\file.txt", SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But I don't know what to #include to make it work.  I tried:

```
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
#include "Windows.h"
#endif
```

based on what I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379283(v=vs.85).aspx).  But when I compile, I get `C3861: 'SetNamedSecurityInfo': identifier not found` (among some other new errors).

When I mouse over my `#include "Windows.h"`, I get the tooltip:  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\Windows.h`, and I can press F2 and jump to that file.  We have other files in our project that include that same Windows.h, and they compile fine.

How do I set file permissions on Windows for everyone to read/write?  If SetNamedSecurityInfo is what I want (I guess SetNamedSecurityInfoW in my case since my users may be running OS's in any language), what do I #include to be able to use it?  Better yet, how do I figure out what to #include, so I know for next time I need to use the Windows API?

Comment: for other newbies:  I got this to compile with this code:  
    #include "Aclapi.h"  
    LPTSTR path=(LPTSTR)dict_path.utf16();  
    SetNamedSecurityInfo(path, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);  
  
But I got a link error, until I also added this in my .pro:  
`win32:LIBS += -ladvapi32`

Comment: can't format my comment above - sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Header
> Aclapi.h
>
> Library
> Advapi32.lib
>
> DLL
> Advapi32.dll

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on Google would probably have had [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) among it top hits. There you can see which header file and library you need.